# How can i add a js file for a specific template/page in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm new with ember, and I want to add some js files for a specific template/page, not for all pages. I included some global js files in ember-cli-build.js , but i need to include others for specific pages IE: for dashboard page i need to add dashboard.js.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Send JavaScript request for that library you need in your Dashboard route - for example in before model.

There's no built in solution for such thing. You could theoretically use Ember Engines, but they are not mature yet. However what you'd be interested in is Lazy Loading.

https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/issues/154